# cannot access wordpress admin panel

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello why is it that when I visit my sites admin address http://www.besogt.com/wp-admin/ yet without the /wp-admin

I get the error

```
 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at
/home/besogt/public_html/wp-content/themes/besogt/functions.php:1) in
/home/besogt/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1174
```

But when accessing the website like an ordinary visitor  http://www.besogt.com it loads fine.

Please help because I cannot login to continue modifying the website. Thanks

Comment: can you please check if there any space at the top of function.php . if yes please remove that and try

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: Hello i have looked at the functions.php file and noticed there was no space at the top